# Custom os ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I am developing my own radius server on PHP and I am using some library of Linux ubuntu 20.04 and another 3rd party like free radius server and apache2 and MySQL server now I want to know how I can create a custom ubuntu server in which my PHP files and all these require files download in one rpm. my clients only install ubuntu server and then install my package using apt-get command.

Comment: The title is misleading. Seems like you merely want a custom *package* that your users can install on top of Ubuntu Server, not a "custom os"

Comment: It may be worthwhile to re-examine the deployment strategy. You can certainly make Apache, PHP, MySQL, and a host of other packages dependencies for yours, but it would add more complexity for your clients. One option would be to wrap your PHP application into a Snap, much like NextCloud. This would drastically simplify things for clients of varying technical skill sets while ensuring everyone is running up-to-date versions of your code.